# How to separate these 2 users with their own content or todo list

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm developing a TODO list like add the data and display in table but when I log in other account I got the same content with other account how to separate the pages with their own content.

Please check the picture below:

[image]

[image]

My code is:

**Dao.java**

```
public class Dao {
    private final static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todolist";
    private final static String user = "root";
    private final static String password = "";
    private final static String dbloader = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final static String ADD = "INSERT INTO `todo`(`TODO`) VALUES (?)";

    public static void Driver(String dbloader) {
        try {
            Class.forName(dbloader);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;

    }

    public static int ADDTODO(Model mod) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Driver(dbloader);
            Connection con = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(ADD);
            pst.setString(1, mod.getTODO());

            i = pst.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return i;

    }
}

**Addtodo**
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String todo = request.getParameter("todo");

        Model mod = new Model();

        mod.setTODO(todo);

        Dao dao = new Dao();

        int i = dao.ADDTODO(mod);

        if (i > 0) {
            response.sendRedirect("Userpage.jsp");
        }

    }
```

**Model.java**

```
public class Model {
    private int ID;
    private String TODO;

    public Model() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Model(int iD, String tODO) {
        super();
        ID = iD;
        TODO = tODO;
    }

    public Model(String tODO) {
        super();
        TODO = tODO;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getTODO() {
        return TODO;
    }

    public void setTODO(String tODO) {
        TODO = tODO;
    }

}
```

**Userpage.jsp**

```
 <form action="Addtodo" method="post">
                        
                        <div class="add-items d-flex"> <input tenter code hereype="text" class="form-control todo-list-input" name="todo" placeholder="What do you need to do today?"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="add" >Add</button></div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you only have one table - todo - that stores the todo items. But since there is no user-specific data in the table, you are bound to get the same data for all users.

Currently, you do not have anything in your table that would differentiate between users.

You need to have 2 tables in your database.

1. Todo

- id
- todo
- userid

2. User

- id
- name
- ..(other relevant fields)

The `userid` field in `Todo` table is a `foreign key` to the `id` field in the `User` table. It acts as a link between the two tables.

So now to get a specific user's todos list, you will run a query like
`SELECT * from todo where userid = user.id`, where `user.id` is the current user's id.

- [SQL foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)
- You could follow this tutorial - which does something similar to what you are doing. [1](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/10/build-todo-app-using-jsp-servlet-jdbc-and-mysql-part1.html), [2](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/10/build-todo-app-using-jsp-servlet-jdbc-and-mysql.html).

Comment: Can you provide a sample code so that I can understand well. Thank you

Comment: @EbenezerAlcontin: this question is far too broad for "sample code". It looks like you have a session system in place already - if you can move from one page to another and retain the signed-in status then your framework is probably using browser cookies to store the session state. You need to find in your framework how to access the user data on the server side.

Comment: Is there a session object in JSP?

Comment: Vijay, your tutorial on javaguides.com appears to be recommending plain-text passwords, a fairly serious security error. I couldn't see whether it made mention of this in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the user's ID/name in each of the Todo item, otherwise you cannot differentiate which To Do item is owned/related to which user.
You have to modify your Model class for `TODO`, add a `int userId` or `string userName` to the model class. And when the user creates a new To do item, you need to set its value as that of the logged in user's ID or name.

Comment: Can you send a sample code so that I can understand well? Tjank you

Answer (score 0):

Hey you might want to take a look at `HttpSession` you can create a session and fill it with your specific user id it will fix your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).